# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'D1'

Tags: python

I have a program /model developed with a Python module. The problem here is that a parameter (a growing chain of a polymer) is predefined as an f-string. I intend to manipulate this parameter to obtain other important mathematical relationships relating to the problem.

For instance, f"D{n}"-is a predefined species (a growing polymer) but, I intend to obtain the expression:

```py
D=104;
max_state=10
for n in range(1,max_state-1):
    Ws=sum(int(f"D{n}"))
print(Ws)
```

I get the following errors:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'D1'

Also,

```py
X=(M0-int(f"D{n}"))/M0
print(X)
```

gives this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'D1'

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't convert a string beginning with `D` to a number.

Comment: The argument to `sum()` should be a sequence of numbers. What are you trying to do by giving it just a single integer?

Comment: Are you trying to do `D * n`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: what number is `D5`, `D87` ?

Comment: How is `D` related to `D1` et al. Are you trying to get the value of *separate* variables named `D1`, `D2`, etc? Use a list, not a bunch of different variables.

Comment: `sum(int(3)` would just be 3 as well. If you want `Ws` to be a *running* sum, you need something like `Ws += ...`.

Comment: if you try to use `f"D{n}"` to create name of variable then it is wrong idea. You should keep values on list or dictionary - ie `values` - instead of variables `D1`, `D2` and then you could use string as key `values["D1"] = 999` and `print( values["D1"] )`

Comment: maybe better show math formula which you want to calculate.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need the D variable in curly braces here, otherwise it gets interpreted as just the character.

Try this instead:

```
f"{D}*{n}"
```